# How to use region updater in magento 2 custom module?

Tags: jquery, magento-2.1.3, country-regions, regions

I am working on the region updater in magento 2. Region Field needs to change based on the selection of country.
Below is my region updater code:

```
 var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('#country', '#region_id',
 '#region', <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo
 $this->helper('Magento\Directory\Helper\Data')->getRegionJson() ?>,
 undefined, '#zip');
```

After updating the above code, I am getting the following error,

> TypeError: this.options.regionJson is undefined
>       http://magento-dev.com/pub/static/version1495188452/frontend/Rosetta/mpw/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/region-updater.js
>       Line 233

Can someone help me to rectify this issue?

Thanks!!!